# Type library exporter encountered a type that derives from a generic class

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, axapta

I want to call a WCF Service which is implemented as a generic class. 
Note: [I have completely no access to modify its classes either to marks it COM visible or to make it as non generic class etc].

I have write a client which consumes that WCF Service. I get warning that:

> "Type library exporter warning processing 'WCFService.MultiService.LokUpServiceClient, WCFService'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a type that derives from a generic class and is not marked as [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]. Class interfaces cannot be exposed for such types. Consider marking the type with [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)] and exposing an explicit interface as the default interface to COM using the ComDefaultInterface attribute".

Question:
To make WCF client COM visible by consuming perfectly WCF Service?
How to get rid of this warning message?

Comment: At the moment of adding a service reference have you tried **deselecting** the option of Reusing existing types?

Comment: Thanks. Its works.

Comment: @ian_scho: Could you make this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment of adding a service reference try deselecting the option of Reusing existing types.

[image: Reuse types in referenced assemblies]

Answer (score 0):

+1 to the accepted answer. I just want to add that if you've already configured a service reference, you can change the Reuse types... setting for the service reference as follows:

1. In the Solution Explorer, find the service reference. It should appear under a **Connected Services** or **Web Services** section.
2. Right-click the service reference and click **Configure Service Reference**. A Settings dialog box appears.
3. Clear the **Reuse types in referenced assemblies** check box.
4. Click **OK**.